# Glassfish not display JSF components

Tags: jsf, netbeans, glassfish, jsf-2

On my index.xhtml I have Java Server Face components which are displayed correctly and use a managed bean. But if I link to any other page or even a page with the EXACT same code those pages will not display these components, only the text.

Suppose index.xhtml is like this and displays correctly:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:inputText value="#{user.name}"/>
            <h:commandButton action="#{user.submit}" value="Submit" />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

If I add a link to any other page (even one with the same code) JSF components are not displayed for them. Is this because the other pages perhaps can't 'see' the managed bean? Or something else?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How does your link look like?

Comment: It's a standard: <a href="other.xhtml" >

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the pages which you want to call are not processed by the Faces Servlet.

In the `web.xml` of your application you define the url-pattern of server requests that will be processed by this servlet. By default this is often `/faces/*`. This means that the link that you call must contain this pattern in order to be processed by the Faces Servlet.

If you create your project with Netbeans, the mapping usually looks like the following:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So try to use links that contain this url pattern or use relative links instead.

If you use `h:link` instead of `a:href`, the url-pattern is automatically prepended:

```
<h:link value="My other page" outcome="otherpage" />
```

will be rendered as:

```
<a href="/yourAppName/faces/otherpage.xhtml">My other page</a>
```