# JSF button is not shown

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish

I have the following code and whatever I do my web browser does not render any submit button.

I am using eclipse with Glassfish.

The problem is also that somehow when I try my examples fast  , the server sometimes hangs around and browser is in the waiting mode for minutes without any error or anything.

Sometimes it does give the page away and it works perfect.

Why is the button not shown and my server is so unstable?

```
<h:head><title>JSF 2: Using @ManagedBean</title>
<link href="./css/styles.css" 
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> 
</h:head>
<h:body>
<div align="center">
<table class="title">
  <tr><th>JSF 2: Using @ManagedBean</th></tr>
</table>
<p/>
<fieldset>
<legend>Random Results Page</legend>
<h:form>
  Press button to get one of three possible results pages.
  <br/>
  <h:commandButton value="Go to Random Page" action="#{navigator.choosePage}" />
</h:form>
</fieldset>
</div>




 package coreservlets;
import javax.faces.bean.*;

@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped 
public class Navigator {
  private String[] resultPages =
    { "page1", "page2", "page3" };

  public String choosePage() {
    return(RandomUtils.randomElement(resultPages));
  }
}
```

Comment: Im trying. How to do that? It turns my html tags into the picture here

Comment: @ArtemMoskalev: You highlight the area with the code and press the `{}` button to get code snippets to be displayed correctly.

Comment: thanks, Keppil. Ilya, there it is.

Comment: Glassfish does not write any mistakes in the log, by the way

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367918/glassfish-not-display-jsf-components?rq=1 there is a probable answer. I tried it and it works, but then there is another question. I always map my Faces servlet to any .jsf pages, if I map it in web.xml rather to .xhtml files - does it make any difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can happen if you *either* forgot to declare the `h:` XML namespace, causing the `<h:xxx>` tags being unrecognized. This can be confirmed by just looking at the JSF source code and the generated HTML output (rightclick - *View Source* in browser).

```html
<html ... xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
```

*Or* the request URL as you see in browser's address bar didn't match the `<url-pattern>` of the `FacesServlet` as mapped in `web.xml`, causing the `<h:xxx>` tags being unparsed. This can be confirmed by just looking at the request URL, the `web.xml` and the generated HTML output.

```xml
<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
```

*Or* the CSS in `styles.css` has hidden it in some way. This can be confirmed by checking the CSS file, and/or using the browser's developer toolset and/or checking the generated HTML output.

```css
input[type=submit] {
    display: none; 
}
```

#### See also:

- [Our JSF wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) - contains a Hello World example and several tutorial links

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, using an application scoped bean for the particular use case is quite strange. It's been shared among all users in all sessions. So if the action is invoked by webapp user X elsewhere in the world, all other webapp users over the world would see it being reflected. Wouldn't you rather use a request or view scoped bean?

#### See also:

- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/7031941#7031941)

Comment: Thanks. The application scope is not my invention - all this code is the example from some tutorial I found online, so I tried to retype it and to launch the application. Which was impossible because of the mistakes in the code there.